# Python code to create lead values for a variable across account with last value of an account as null

Tags: python, lag, lead

I have a a very large dataset containing id and data points of time series (with some missing values). The following is just an example.

I will need to create a lead variable for a variable across groups built on account id such that last value across each account id is null. Please refer below for more clarity.

```
id    time    value    lag_value 
A     2000    10       11     
A     2001    11       Nan 
B     2002    1        2
B     2003    2        3 
B     2004    3        Nan
```

Comment: @mechanical_meat

Comment: Does this work for you?: `df['lag_value'] = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].shift(-1)`

Comment: Thank you! It works.